# How to sync our app contacts into native contact app on android programmatically

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contacts

I want to sync my contacts from my app to native android  contact app programmatically. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want to sync my contacts from my app to....." How can you have contacts in your app??

Comment: If you have some numbers to be stored in contacts... here is the answer..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android

Comment: i have to sync my contacts with my selected ringtone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try below code for account syncing

```
public static void requestSyncNow(final Context context) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
            Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
            boolean isMasterSyncOn = ContentResolver.getMasterSyncAutomatically();


            for (Account account : accounts) {
                Log.d(TAG, "account=" + account);

                int isSyncable = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(account,
                        ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);
                boolean isSyncOn = ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(account,
                        ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);
                Log.d(TAG, "Syncable=" + isSyncable + " SyncOn=" + isSyncOn);
                if (isSyncable > 0 /* && isSyncOn */) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "request Sync");
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
                    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, bundle);
                }
            }

        }
    }, "SyncLauncher").start();
}
```