# How to add ringtone to native app contacts programmatically in android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, ringtone

I know how to create contact with name,mobile number,email id for native app programmatically using [How to add new contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android). But I do not know how to create contact with ringtone. Please help me. Thanks in advance

I got the solution to add the ringtone after adding the contacts into native app:

```
String select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" +first_name+ "\" )"; 

Cursor c1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

startManagingCursor(c1);

int id=0;

if (c1.moveToNext()) {

id = new Integer(c1.getString(0)).intValue();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONTACT ID: "+id+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

} 

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 

cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

ContentValues values=new ContentValues(); values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, newgroup_ringtone); 
cr.update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values, Contacts._ID + "=" + id, null);
```

Comment: How to Insert new contacts with Ringtone? please help me i need very urgent

Comment: Following codes are not working for me to add contacts with ringtone.It shows insert failed exception                           try
 {
 if(ringtonepath != null)
 {
 
 
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, ringtonepath)
          
         .build()
     );
 }
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add the contact first then retrieve that contact and update the contact with the ringtone with code like this:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ?", new String[] {id})
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED, starred)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL, sendToVoicemail)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, ringtone)
        .build());

try {
    resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
}
```