# adding contact automatically in phone book in android app

Tags: android, contacts

I need to add a contact automatically in phone book by my app....I found this link..

[How to add new contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android/4744442#4744442)

using this, I am able to add phone no.,name,email etc. But don't know how to add photo.

Comment: I tried using this...   ImageView img  = new ImageView(this); img.setImageResource((R.drawable.ic_launcher)); ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)                 .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)                       .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, img)                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,img) .build());                  but didn't work

Comment: convert it to bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Firstly convert your image to bitmap and then use below code for adding photo to your contact.

```
OnClickListener addClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Getting reference to Name EditText
                EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

                // Getting reference to Mobile EditText
                EditText etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mobile);

                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                        new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                int rawContactID = ops.size();

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert a new raw contact in the table ContactsContract.RawContacts
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert display name in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, etName.getText().toString())
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Mobile Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etMobile.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                if(mBitmap!=null){    // If an image is selected successfully
                    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG , 75, stream);

                    // Adding insert operation to operations list
                    // to insert Photo in the table ContactsContract.Data
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,stream.toByteArray())
                            .build());

                    try {
                        stream.flush();
                    }catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try{
                    // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```

For more details please refer below link 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/programatically-adding-contacts-with-photo-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/

Answer (score 0):

Use following code this takes picture as photoByteArray for the method

```
 private void addContact2() {
 final String displayName = "XYZA";
 final String mobileNumber = "666666";
 final byte[] photoByteArray; // initalized elsewhere

 ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "")
    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "")
    .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
    //.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, displayName)
    .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photoByteArray)
    .build());

Uri newContactUri = null;
ContentProviderResult[] res = null;
try {
final ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
res = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
if (res != null && res.length > 0 && res[0] != null) {
    newContactUri = res[0].uri;
    Log.d(CallActivity.class.getName(), "URI added contact:"+ newContactUri);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully added " + displayName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else Log.e(CallActivity.class.getName(), "Contact not added.");
} catch (NullPointerException | RemoteException |   OperationApplicationException e) {
Log.e(CallActivity.class.getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
 }
 }
```