# Inserting a new contact programmatically through my app without using Intent

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts

I am working with an app in with I am interacting with phone contacts.
I want to add a new Contact to my phones Contacts List. I have tried the following code but it is not work:

```
void addContact(Context ctx, PreviewContactModel model) {

        ArrayList<Contact_Model> contact_models = handler.getAllContacts();

        Contact_Model contact_model = new Contact_Model();

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contentProviderOperation = new ArrayList<>();

        int rawContactID = Integer.parseInt(contact_models.get(contact_models.size() - 1).getContactId()) + 1;

        contact_model.setContactId(String.valueOf(rawContactID));

        contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());

        contact_model.setContactAccount(new ContactAccount(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE));

        // ------------------------------------------------------ Names
        if (model.getName() != null) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            model.getName()).build());
            contact_model.setContactName(model.getName());
        }

        // First Name

        if (!model.getFirstName().equals("")) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                            model.getFirstName()).build());
            contact_model.setFirstName(model.getFirstName());
        }


        // Last Name
        if (!model.getLastName().equals("")) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                            model.getLastName()).build());
            contact_model.setLastName(model.getLastName());
        }

        //  Contact Photo

        if (model.getContactPhoto() != null) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, model.getContactPhoto())
                    .build());

            try {
                contact_model.setContactPhoto(new String(model.getContactPhoto(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // Contact Note

        if (!model.getNote().equals("")){
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE, model.getNote())
                    .build());
            contact_model.setNote(model.getNote());
        }

        // Contact Birthday Date

        if (!model.getDob().equals("")){
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.DATA, model.getDob())
                    .build());
            contact_model.setDob(model.getDob());
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number
        if (model.getMap().get(0) != null) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            model.getMap().get(0))
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build());
            contact_model.setContactNumber(model.getMap().get(0));
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
        if (model.getMap().size() > 1) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            model.getMap().get(1))
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
        if (model.getMap().size() > 2) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            model.getMap().get(2))
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------ workEmail
        if (model.getEmail().size() > 0) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                            model.getEmail().get(0))
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
            contact_model.setContactEmail(model.getEmail().get(0));
        }
        // ------------------------------------------------------ homeEmail
        if (model.getEmail().size() > 1) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                            model.getEmail().get(1))
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());
        }
        // ------------------------------------------------------ Organization
        if (!model.getOrganization().equals("") && !model.getJob().equals("")) {
            contentProviderOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,
                            model.getOrganization())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE,
                            model.getJob())
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
            contact_model.setOrganization(model.getOrganization());
            contact_model.setJob(model.getJob());
        }
        // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
        try {
            ctx.getContentResolver()
                    .applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contentProviderOperation);
            handler.addContact(contact_model);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //show exception in toast
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what kind of `Exception` did you get? what does `"it is not work"` mean?

Comment: I didn't get any Exception @pskink. When function is call no Exception Occurs and when I check my phones Contact list the Contact has not being added.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
        String displayName  = "ABC";
        String emailID      = "abc@mail.com";
        String mobileNumber = "88888888";
        String homeNumber   = "1111";
        String workNumber   = "2222";
        String company      = "xyz";
        String jobTitle     = "boss";

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contentProviderOperationArrayList = new ArrayList <ContentProviderOperation> ();

        contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());

        //Name
        if (displayName != null) {
            contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            displayName).build());
        }

        //Mobile Number
        if (mobileNumber != null) {
            contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                    newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, mobileNumber)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build());
        }

        //Home
        if (homeNumber != null) {
            contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, homeNumber)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());
        }

        //Work
        if (workNumber != null) {
            contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, workNumber)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
        }

        //Email
        if (emailID != null) {
            contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
        }

        //Organization
        if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
            contentProviderOperationArrayList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
        }

        // Creating new contact
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contentProviderOperationArrayList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(yourContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: I have use this code @Febi Mathew but it is not working, same issue. Contact is not being added to contact list with no exception. And I have also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4744514/6583944)

Comment: Check whether you have added the required permissions in your manifest. Also check whether your application is granted to add contacts if you are using device running Marshmallow and above.

Comment: Yes I have added both read and write permission in manifest '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />' and Grant permission at run time @Fabi Mathew.

Comment: @FebiMFelix how to add contact note or how to add contact tag to know contact added from my application

Comment: Did you tried ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NOTES ?