# How to save a contact in phone via intent? Or something using android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am  working on a business card reader app for digitalizing purposes. I have successfully got the recognition result in the form of XML. I have also parsed that XML file and extracted out the fields such as name, email, mobile no.

How can I save this data in my phone contact via my app?

Comment: Use this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android

Answer (score 2):

```
// Creates a new Intent to insert a contact
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
// Sets the MIME type to match the Contacts Provider
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

/*
 * Inserts new data into the Intent. This data is passed to the
 * contacts app's Insert screen
 */
// Inserts an email address
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, mEmailAddress.getText())
/*
 * In this example, sets the email type to be a work email.
 * You can set other email types as necessary.
 */
      .putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
// Inserts a phone number
      .putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, mPhoneNumber.getText())
/*
 * In this example, sets the phone type to be a work phone.
 * You can set other phone types as necessary.
 */
      .putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
```

Source: [Insert a New Contact Using an Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html#InsertContact)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Contacts Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Intent` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

Put some `Extras` in your intent like *EMAIL* or *PHONE_TYPE* :

```
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "email@email.com");
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, "15417543010");
```

and don't forget at the end to start the `Activity` :

```
startActivity(intent);
```